# How to fill webpage (Google) values using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to fill Google account registration form values using excel vba. I'm getting errors while filling below fields. Kindly advise.

Webpage Link - (Google Registration Page)
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default

1) Month Combobox 
2) Gender Combobox

The code that I'm using to fill above fields is

wb.Document.GetElementById("HiddenBirthMonth").Value = 1
wb.Document.GetElementById("HiddenGender").Value = "Male"

Where WB is the object of "WebBrowser"

Comment: I'have used fields names as "HiddenBirthMonth" & "HiddenGender". still I'm not able to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look to Google's form page code you can notice both fields are dropdowns.
To customize the dropdown Google used a workaround making both Gender and BirthMonth hidden fields and giving them these ids:

- HiddenBirthMonth
- HiddenGender

Comment: I'have used fields names as "HiddenBirthMonth" & "HiddenGender". still I'm not able to update the values.

Comment: Using those fields you are unable to see field filled in or to send the form?

Comment: Using those fields i'm unable to see field filled in.

Comment: The fields are filled in by a javascript routine wich fills both the hidden box (real value sent) and the label on the dropdown. If you want to see them change without making hard analysis on the lib used for the form I sudgest you to disable JavaScript, so google will send you a page with BirthMonth and Gender as plain fields thus the code without Hidden should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the send key to put the information or select options.
But while using send keys you should loose the focus from webpage.
Ti use send keys code first do manually and identify the sequence.